# jQuery plugins vs widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

Few months ago I started some experiments with jQuery plugin. I found some tutorials on the Interenet and I started to put something together.
A couple of days ago I had the need to build my own "plugin" and got back to my old project. Trying to find some more informations on the internet, I bumped in these new "things" called widgets.

For what I understand I should forget about plugins and start developing widgets. 
Are the plugins an old concept or are still valid?
What is the best approach if you need a custom jquery control with interface?

I am using extensively jQuery UI.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can either write a **jQuery plugin** or a **jQuery UI widget**.

Depends on what you want to do. Neither of these is *outdated*. If you write a widget, it will depend on jQuery UI (and jQuery of course), if you write a plugin, it will only depend on jQuery. Really, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My confusion started when I read this article: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/ This guy has converted is "tool" into a widget from a plugin.

Comment: @LeftyX I guess he made a decision that for depending on one more library, he will get some more nice ready functions, events and stuff. Might be easier to develop, but your plugin/widget can't be used if jQuery UI is not used for the project.

Answer (score 28):

I had an equivalent question my self and I stumble on [this](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/why-use-the-widget-factory/)  (jQuery Documentation):

> #### Stateless vs. Stateful Plugins
>
> Most jQuery plugins are stateless; they perform some action and their
> job is done. For example, if you set the text of an element using
> `.text( "hello" )`, there is no setup phase and the result is always
> the same. For these types of plugins, it makes sense to just extend
> jQuery's prototype.
>
> However, some plugins are stateful; they have full life cycles,
> maintain state, and react to changes. These plugins require a lot of
> code dedicated to initialization and state management (and sometimes
> destruction). This results in a lot of boilerplate for building
> stateful plugins. Even worse, each plugin author may manage life
> cycles and state differently, resulting in different API styles for
> different plugins. The widget factory aims to solve both problems,
> removing the boilerplate and creating a consistent API across plugins.
>
> #### Consistent API
>
> The widget factory defines how to create and destroy widgets, get and
> set options, invoke methods, and listen to events triggered by the
> widget. By using the widget factory to build your stateful plugins,
> you are automatically conforming to a defined standard, making it
> easier for new users to start using your plugins. In addition to
> defining the interface, the widget factory also implements much of
> this functionality for you. (...)
>
> #### Setting Options on Initialization
>
> Whenever you build a plugin that accepts options, you should define
> defaults for as many options as possible, then merge the user-provided
> options with the defaults on initialization. (...) The widget factory
> provides this functionality and even takes it a bit further.

I'm posting here for feature reference since this is where I'm first looking for an answer! :)

Comment: That's much better... 
Better to quote than just posting links?!! or Both !!!
I'll keep it in mind next time... :)